# XML parsing in swift not working, no errors

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse a xml file direct from a URL the code has no errors, and the app opens fine but the tableview is empty. here is the link and the code I have used, if I can get some guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

I initially built this through a tutorial (just learning the ropes)

```
import UIKit

class firecallViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate{

@IBOutlet var tbData: UITableView?


var parser = NSXMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var title1 = NSMutableString()
var date = NSMutableString()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.beginParsing()
}

func beginParsing()
{
    posts = []
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"https://example.com/bushfirealert/bushfireAlert.xml"))!)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    tbData!.reloadData()
}

//XMLParser Methods

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    element = elementName
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
    {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString()
        title1 = ""
        date = NSMutableString()
        date = ""
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
        if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
        }
        if !date.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
        }
        
        posts.addObject(elements)
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if element.isEqualToString("title") {
        title1.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
        date.appendString(string)
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!
    
    if(cell.isEqual(NSNull)) {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UITableViewCell;
    }
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("date") as! NSString as String
    
    return cell as UITableViewCell
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code to see where it goes and what it does and what it doesn't?

Comment: If this tutorial suggests those horrible initializations in `parser:didStartElement:..` look for a better one.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated answer*

You told me in the comments that you don't have to use NSXMLParser.

In this case, I have an easy solution for your parsing: use [CheatyXML](https://github.com/lobodart/CheatyXML), a very simple library.

First, follow the easy [install intructions](https://github.com/lobodart/CheatyXML#installation).

Then make a parser with your URL:

```
import CheatyXML

let feedUrl = NSURL(string: "https://example.com/bushfirealert/bushfireAlert.xml")!
let parser = XMLParser(contentsOfURL: feedUrl)
```

And safely unwrap all values as if you were subscripting dictionaries, and use the `.string` property to get the string fields contents.

Like this:

```
if let parser = parser,
    channel = parser["channel"],
    title = channel["title"].string,
    link = channel["link"].string,
    description = channel["description"].string,
    docs = channel["docs"].string,
    generator = channel["generator"].string {
        print(title)
        print(link)
        print(description)
        print(docs)
        print(generator)
}
```

Result:

> QFES Current Incidents
> http://bneags01.desqld.internal/publicfeed/PublicRssFeed.aspx
> QFES Current Incidents
> http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification
> Argotic Syndication Framework

Now instead of my series of `print` you call a method of yours to populate your variables and then you reload the table view, and you're set.

---

*Old answer*

NSXMLParser works asynchronously, so when you reload your table in `beginParsing()`, the data is not parsed *yet*.

You need to reload the table *when the parser has finished parsing*.

Luckily, there's a callback for that.

Remove `tbData!.reloadData()` from `beginParsing()` and add this delegate method to your view controller instead:

```
func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    tbData!.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Ok I have had a play I can now get rid of the errors, and compile, but I get zero data displayed. I think I might just start at square 1 with this one.

Comment: Add `print("done")` (or a breakpoint) in `parserDidEndDocument` to verify if the control flow goes there as expected. It will help debug where's the actual issue.

Comment: Nothing at all, as I said a bit new to this I clearly have done something wrong, for review here is my revised code.

Comment: actually, I cant figure out how to show you the code :)

Comment: You can link to a GitHub Gist for example. Or, if the code is not too long, update your question.

Comment: I can't help you with NSXMLParser on this project, it bores me to death, sorry. *But* if you're ok to use a third-party library instead of NSXMLParser then I have a working already-made solution for you. Interested to have that as an answer, or do you *need* to use NSXMLParser?

Comment: no I am not commited to NSXMLParser I am happy to play with any workable solution.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I have tried this and it compiles but breaks, I assume from the table view? I dont get the result you did below [link](https://gist.github.com/damienkeffyn/46ecb1dca3ad93b4ba2a1e439238203a)] here is another file.

Comment: Sorry mate, I've done enough on this one. I hope you'll find help from someone else or that you will eventually get how it works. Good luck. :)